# Creating a new array column type dynamically

Tags: macros, expansion, arrays

I am evaluating toks registers for various uses - they are still fairly new to me. I'm using them to construct a table column-wise. During this, I have come across an issue I have failed to find a solution for. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newtoks\toksFormat
\newtoks\toksLine

\toksFormat = {lcr}
\toksLine   = {first & second & third}

\begin{document}

  % this works
  \newcolumntype{X}{clr}
  \begin{longtable}{|X|}
    \hline
    \the\toksLine \tabularnewline
    \hline
  \end{longtable}

  % this doesn't
  \newcolumntype{X}{\the\toksFormat}
  \begin{longtable}{|X|}
    \hline
    \the\toksLine \tabularnewline
    \hline
  \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

As the documentation of the package `array` states, great care is taken not to evaluate the preamble. I suppose that is what's causing the error message in the second table:

```
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\the): `c' used.
```

I'm not sure whether this is an `array` issue at all, it might just be down to some plain TeX magic I do not (yet) know of. Is it somehow possible to force the expansion of `\the\toksFormat` inside the call to `\newcolumntype`?

Comment: In the future please don't use backticks `\`` in the title because it will not be rendered by design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\edef\tmp{\noexpand\newcolumntype{X}{\the\toksFormat}}
\tmp
```

But there really is no advantage to using the register here.

Answer (score 3):

You have to expand, yes. Here are a couple of tricks (I learned the `#{` one from Heiko Oberdiek).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\def\enewcolumntype#1#2#{\@enewcolumntype{#1}{#2}}
\def\@enewcolumntype#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \unexpanded{\newcolumntype{#1}#2}{#3}}\x
}
\makeatother

\newtoks\toksFormat
\newtoks\toksLine

\toksFormat = {lcr}
\toksLine   = {first & second & third}

\begin{document}

\enewcolumntype{X}{\the\toksFormat}
\begin{tabular}{|X|}
\hline
\the\toksLine \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\toksFormat = {lp{#1}r}

\enewcolumntype{X}[1]{\the\toksFormat}
\begin{tabular}{|X{5cm}|}
\hline
\the\toksLine \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]